# Creating Client ID in Developer console keeps throwing Server error

Tags: google-api, sha1

When I try to **create Client ID** with my Android game's fingerprint and package, it throws a **Server Error (with Tracking number: undefined)**. With any other fingerprint and package combination, it works fine. Could Google fix it somehow? Seems like my fingerprint and package is broken, but my game is already published, so I must use them.

Server error, tracking number: undefined

Comment: Same error but I also have the "Tracking number : undefined" error when using their example package "com.google.GooglePlusSample"

Comment: I wasn't able to fix this, so I created a new Google Play Console Application with same name but different package (I replaced one letter with capital). Then I was able to create Client ID for it with no problem. Weird issue :/

Comment: Mmh, too bad, I already have users with this client ID and can't export the existing ones... I will mail them :) Thanks a lot tho